# Windows Server 2003 SiSRaid Error, \Device\SCSI\SiSRaid1?

Tags: windows-server-2003, drivers

Following up to [[Write-read errors, Raid1 recovery?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52312/write-read-errors-raid1-recovery](my) Raid question), I noticed an error in my event log:

"The driver for device \Device\Scsi\SiSRaid1 detected a port timeout due to prolonged inactivity. All associated busses were reset in an effort to clear the condition."

Could this be the rotten stuff in my server? Could a plain small driver update save my skin?

If not, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of it, the SiS based Raid Controller isn't responding to the system. Is this on the same computer as the earlier question? From the looks of it, it might be a faulty raid controller or if the controller has Battery-backed write cache, it could be the memory going bad.

I'd attempt a driver update but to me this sounds like a raid controller failure. If its SiS, its probably a cheaper firmware-based one. If this system is mission critical it would be extremely wise to fork out the money for a full featured hardware based raid controller w/battery backed write cache. If anything, because they tend to have much better support and a very useful onboard tools for diagnosing these kinds of issues.

For more information on the differences, check out the Wikipedia article on RAID, it has info on the difference between full-featured hardware and firmware/driver based raid controllers.

Comment: I didn't even realize I forgot the link. This takes you to the relevant section about RAID controllers. -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Firmware.2Fdriver-based_RAID

Comment: Just checked the driver version, it's dated from 2003. There exist a 2007 version. Did I already say I was out of here soon?

Comment: This has been suggested to the boss as a terribly urgent and important issue. He doesn't seem to care. This is a lone fight, and/or an apocalypse.